# Bit counting in a contiguous memory chunk

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was asked in an interview the following question.

```
int countSetBits(void *ptr, int start, int end);
```

**Synopsis:** 
Assume that `ptr` points to a big chunk of memory. Viewing this memory as contiguous sequence of bits, `start` and `end` are bit positions. Assume `start` and `end` 
have proper values and `ptr` is pointing to an initialized chunck of memory.

**Question:** 
Write a C code to count number of bits set from `start` to `end` [inclusive] and return the count.

Just to make it more clear

```
 ptr---->+-------------------------------+
         | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
         +-------------------------------+
         | 8 | 9 |                   |15 |
         +-------------------------------+
         |                               |
         +-------------------------------+
              ...
              ...
         +-------------------------------+
         |               | S |           |
         +-------------------------------+
              ...
              ...
         +-------------------------------+
         |    | E |                      |
         +-------------------------------+
              ...
              ...
```

My solution:

```
int countSetBits(void *ptr, int start, int end )
{
    int count = 0, idx; 

    char *ch; 

    for (idx = start; idx <= end; idx++) 
    {     ch = ptr + (idx/8); 

          if((128 >> (idx%8)) & (*ch)) 
          {
                   count++; 
          }
    }

    return count; 
}
```

I gave a very lengthy and somewhat inefficient code during the interview. I worked on it later and came up with above solution.

I am very sure SO community can provide more elegant solution. I am just curious to see their response.

PS: Above code is not compiled. It is more like a pseudo code and may contain errors.

Comment: I think you probably missed the point. It's going to be much more efficient if your main loop works in bytes not bits, so you  have `for (int i = ...; ...; ++i) count += bits_per_byte[((unsigned char*)ptr)[i]]`. Where bits_per_byte is a precomputed array of 256 values holding the number of set bits for each possible byte value. You have a bit of messing around to do at the start and end of your loop where you don't have a whole byte to play with.

Comment: I think they wanted you to demonstrate lookup table usage. Assuming 8-bit chars, you make a 256-long array that maps a character to number of bits in it. 1You can do the same with 16-bit quantities of course, or with anything that is not too big and efficiently addressed.

Comment: I'm not sure with the start/end value. Do they mean bit offset or byte offset or what?

Comment: Do the start and end indexes count from the MSB to the LSB inside the bytes or the other way around?

Comment: @harold: that's not clearly specified, and I would expect that this question would have to be asked in the interview. The example `countSetBits()` function in the question counts from MSB to LSB.

Comment: Edit your tag this is not c++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most quick and efficient way to my opinion is to use a table of 256 entries, where every element represents number of bits in the index. Index is a next byte from the memory location.

something like this:

```
int bit_table[256] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, ...};
char* p = ptr + start;
int count = 0;
for (p; p != ptr + end; p++)
    count += bit_table[*(unsigned char*)p];
```

Comment: But an important part of the problem is that `start` and `end` are bit indexes - not byte indexes. And they might not be on even byte boundaries (and the fact that they could be within the same byte adds another boundary condition).

Comment: yepp, this is a good optimization for most part of the range but you have to use something else for the boundaries.

Comment: I agree, bit-boundary conditions are not taken into account in my example; it's not difficult to add manual counting for 2 boundary bytes.

Comment: @dimitri: don't forget that in addition to the scenario where there are two 'book-end' bytes around buffer of full bytes (make sure you handle the situation where there are zero full bytes between the book-ends), there's another boundary condition where the range of bits is contained within a single byte. That situation likely needs different special treatment if you're going to use a table lookup to count set bits (the OP's brute-force counter didn't need special case handling for this).

Comment: Accepted this response as it is certainly a very quick solution. However, we can do some optimization, even in the context of an interview. Such as using a lookup array of size 16 to represent set bits in lower octet. @Michael Burr and Jiri used them below.

Comment: @dimitri, did you actually benchmark this? RAM access is 200-300 cycles on modern machines, cache access is few dozen (depending on level) and registers are essentially instantaneous. Lookup table will put a pressure on processor's memory hierarchy, which *may* wipe-out any performance gained from lowering the amount of calculation. On modern processors with deep memory hierarchies, it is often faster to do more calculation and less memory access than the other way around. I'm not claiming this is the case here, but it's hard to know without benchmarking!

Comment: The question clearly says start and end are BIT positions. This code is wrong, as the guy who marked it right.

Answer (score 9):

Boundary conditions, they get no respect...

Everyone here seems to be concentrating on the lookup table to count the bits.  And that's OK, but I think that even more important when answering an interview question is to make sure you handle the boundary conditions.

The look up table is just an optimization. *It's much more important to get the answer right* than to get it fast. If this were my interview, going straight for the lookup table without even mentioning that there are some tricky details about handling the first few and last few bits that aren't on full-byte boundaries would be worse than coming up with a solution that counted each bit ploddingly, but got the boundary conditions right.

So I think Bhaskar's solution in his question is probably superior to the most of the answers mentioned here - it seems to handle the boundary conditions.

Here's a solution that uses a lookup table and tries to still handle the boundaries (it's only lightly tested, so I won't claim that it's 100% correct).  It's also uglier than I'd like, but it's late:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

static
size_t bits_in_byte( uint8_t val)
{
    static int const half_byte[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4 };

    int result1 = half_byte[val & 0x0f];
    int result2 = half_byte[(val >> 4) & 0x0f];

    return result1 + result2;
}


int countSetBits( void* ptr, int start, int end) 
{
    uint8_t*    first;
    uint8_t*    last;
    int         bits_first;
    int         bits_last;
    uint8_t     mask_first;
    uint8_t     mask_last;

    size_t count = 0;

    // get bits from the first byte
    first = ((uint8_t*) ptr) + (start / 8);
    bits_first = 8 - start % 8;
    mask_first = (1 << bits_first) - 1;
    mask_first = mask_first << (8 - bits_first);


    // get bits from last byte
    last = ((uint8_t*) ptr) + (end / 8);
    bits_last = 1 + (end % 8);
    mask_last = (1 << bits_last) - 1;

    if (first == last) {
        // we only have a range of bits in  the first byte
        count = bits_in_byte( (*first) & mask_first & mask_last);        
    }
    else {
        // handle the bits from the first and last bytes specially
        count += bits_in_byte((*first) & mask_first);
        count += bits_in_byte((*last) & mask_last);

        // now we've collected the odds and ends from the start and end of the bit range
        // handle the full bytes in the interior of the range

        for (first = first+1; first != last; ++first) {
            count += bits_in_byte(*first);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Note that a detail that would have to be worked out as part of the interview is whether the bits within a byte are indexed starting at the least-significant-bit (lsb) or most-significant-bit (msb). In other words, if the start index were specified as 0, would a byte with the value 0x01 or a byte with the value 0x80 have the bit set in that index? Sort of like deciding whether the indexes consider the bit order within a byte as big-endian or little-endian.

There's no 'right' answer for this - the interviewer would have to specify what the behavior should be. I'll also note that my example solution handles this in the opposite way to the OP's example code (I was going by how I interpreted the diagram, with the indexes reading as 'bit numbers' as well). The OPs' solution considers the bit order as big-endian, my function treats them as little-endian. So even though both handle partial bytes at the star & end of the range, they'll give different answers. Which is the right answer depends on what the actual spec for the problem is.

Comment: +1: it's about pointless to go faster, when you're heading straight into a wall, at best you'll only die faster...

Answer (score 4):

The version of @dimitri is likely the fastest. But it is difficult to build the table of bit counts for all 128 8-bit chars in an interview. You can get a very fast version with a table for 16 hex numbers 0x0, 0x1, ..., 0xF, that you can build easily:

```
int countBits(void *ptr, int start, int end) {
    // start, end are byte indexes
    int hexCounts[16] =   {0, 1, 1, 2,   1, 2, 2, 3,
                           1, 2, 3, 3,   2, 3, 3, 4}; 
    unsigned char * pstart = (unsigned char *) ptr + start;
    unsigned char * pend = (unsigned char *) ptr + end;
    int count = 0;
    for (unsigned char * p = pstart; p <= pend; ++p) {
        unsigned char b = *p;
        count += hexCounts[b & 0x0F] + hexCounts[(b >> 4) & 0x0F];
    }
    return count;
}
```

EDIT: If `start` and `end` are bit indexes then the bits in the first and last bytes would be counted first before the above function is called:

```
int countBits2(void *ptr, int start, int end) {
    // start, end are bit indexes
    if (start > end) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char* pstart = (unsigned char *) ptr + start/8; // first byte
    unsigned char* pend = (unsigned char *) ptr + end/8;     // last byte
    int istart = start % 8;                                  // index in first byte
    int iend = end % 8;                                      // index in last byte 
    unsigned char b = *pstart;                               // byte
    if (pstart == pend) {                                    // count in 1 byte only
        b = b << istart;
        for (int i = istart; i <= iend; ++i) {               // between istart, iend
            if (b & 0x80) ++count; 
            b = b << 1;
        }
    }
    else {                                                   // count in 2 bytes
        for (int i = istart; i < 8; ++i) {                   // from istart to 7
            if (b & 1) ++count; 
            b = b >> 1;
        }
        b = *pend;
        for (int i = 0; i <= iend; ++i) {                    // from 0 to iend
            if (b & 0x80) ++count; 
            b = b << 1;
        }
    }
    return count + countBits(ptr, start/8 + 1, end/8 - 1);
}
```

Comment: countBits2() doesn't pass the correct start and end indexes to countBits(). And even if it did, it would over count bits if the start and end range were contained within a single byte (for example if `start == 4` and `end == 5`).

Comment: @Michael: thanks for the hint. Corrected now, hopefully OK. This would have been a long interview! :).

Comment: it was more painful handling those corner cases than you thought, right? (it certainly was for me). Now you're left with a couple minor bugs/typos in the `count += ...` line of the original `countBits()` function.

Comment: I see - corrected. Well, it would need some more tests before going into production. But as an idea should be sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed - I think that at an actual interview just pointing out that the issues need to be addressed would be the main thing. But if this were a "homework" problem from an interview (which seem to be more and more popular), I would definitely be looking for all corner cases to be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent recent study comparing several of the most modern techniques for counting the ***number of 'set' (1-valued) bits*** in a range of memory (*aka* [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), *bitset cardinality*, *sideways sum*, *population count* or [`popcnt`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679649), *etc.*) can be found in Wojciech, Kurz, and Lemire (2017), [*Faster population counts using AVX2 instructions*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07612.pdf) <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69xAm.png)</sup>

The following is a complete, tested, and fully-working **C#** adaptation of the "Harley-Seal" algorithm from that paper, which the authors found to be the fastest method that uses general-purpose bitwise operations (that is, that doesn't require special hardware).

**1. Managed array entry points**
(optional) Provides access to the block-optimized bit-counting for managed array `ulong[]`.

```
/// <summary> Returns the total number of 1-valued bits in the array </summary>
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static int OnesCount(ulong[] rg) => OnesCount(rg, 0, rg.Length);

/// <summary> Finds the total number of '1' bits in an array or its subset </summary>
/// <param name="rg"> Array of ulong values to scan </param>
/// <param name="index"> Starting index in the array </param>
/// <param name="count"> Number of ulong values to examine, starting at 'i' </param>
public static int OnesCount(ulong[] rg, int index, int count)
{
    if ((index | count) < 0 || index > rg.Length - count)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    fixed (ulong* p = &rg[index])
        return OnesCount(p, count);
}
```

**2. Scalar API**
Used by the block-optimized counter to aggregate results from the carry-save adder, and also to finish up any remainder for block sizes not divisible by the optimized chunk size of 16 x 8 bytes/ulong = 128 bytes. Suitable for general-purpose use also.

```
/// <summary> Finds the Hamming Weight or ones-count of a ulong value </summary>
/// <returns> The number of 1-bits that are set in 'x' </returns>
public static int OnesCount(ulong x)
{
    x -= (x >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555;
    x = ((x >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333) + (x & 0x3333333333333333);
    return (int)((((x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 0x0101010101010101) >> 56);
}
```

**3. *"Harley-Seal"* block-optimized 1s-bit counter**
Processes blocks of 128 bytes at a time, i.e., 16 `ulong` values per block. Uses the carry-save adder (shown below) to gang-add single bits across adjacent `ulong`s, and aggregates totals upwards as powers of two.

```
/// <summary> Count the number of 'set' (1-valued) bits in a range of memory. </summary>
/// <param name="p"> Pointer to an array of 64-bit ulong values to scan </param>
/// <param name="c"> Size of the memory block as a count of 64-bit ulongs </param>
/// <returns> The total number of 1-bits </returns>
public static int OnesCount(ulong* p, int c)
{
    ulong z, y, x, w;
    int c = 0;

    for (w = x = y = z = 0UL; cq >= 16; cq -= 16)
        c += OnesCount(CSA(ref w,
                            CSA(ref x,
                                CSA(ref y,
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++),
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++)),
                                CSA(ref y,
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++),
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++))),
                            CSA(ref x,
                                CSA(ref y,
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++),
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++)),
                                CSA(ref y,
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++),
                                    CSA(ref z, *p++, *p++)))));

    c <<= 4;
    c += (OnesCount(w) << 3) + (OnesCount(x) << 2) + (OnesCount(y) << 1) + OnesCount(z);

    while (--cq >= 0)
        c += OnesCount(*p++);

    return c;
}
```

**4. Carry-save adder (CSA)**

```
/// <summary> carry-save adder </summary>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static ulong CSA(ref ulong a, ulong b, ulong c)
{
    ulong v = a & b | (a ^ b) & c;
    a ^= b ^ c;
    return v;
}
```

---

**Remarks**

Because the approach shown here counts the total number of 1-bits by proceeding 128-byte chunks at a time, it only becomes optimal with larger memory block sizes. For example, likely at least some (small) multiple of that sixteen-qword (16-`ulong`) chunk size. For counting 1-bits in smaller memory ranges, this code will work correctly, but drastically underperform more naïve methods. See the paper for details.

From the paper, this diagram summarizes how the [Carry-Save Adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder) works:

[image: Carry-Save Adder in 'Harley-Seal' block-optimized bit count]

---

**References**

[1.]  Muła, Wojciech, Nathan Kurz, and Daniel Lemire. "Faster population counts using AVX2 instructions." The Computer Journal 61, no. 1 (2017): 111-120.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: No attempt to compile the following code has been made.

```
/*
 * Table counting the number of set bits in a byte.
 * The byte is the index to the table.
 */
uint8_t  table[256] = {...};

/***************************************************************************
 *
 * countBits - count the number of set bits in a range
 *
 * The most significant bit in the byte is considered to be bit 0.
 *
 * RETURNS: 0 on success, -1 on failure
 */
int countBits (
    uint8_t *  buffer,
    int        startBit,  /* starting bit */
    int        endBit,    /* End-bit (inlcusive) */
    unsigned * pTotal     /* Output: number of consecutively set bits */
    ) {
    int      numBits;     /* number of bits left to check */
    int      mask;        /* mask to apply to byte from <buffer> */
    int      bits;        /* # of bits to end of byte */
    unsigned count = 0;   /* total number of bits set */
    uint8_t  value;       /* value read from the buffer */

    /* Return -1 if parameters fail sanity check (skipped) */

    numBits   = (endBit - startBit) + 1;

    index  = startBit >> 3;
    bits   = 8 - (startBit & 7);
    mask   = (1 << bits) - 1;

    value = buffer[index] & mask;  /* mask-out any bits preceding <startBit> */
    numBits -= bits;

    while (numBits > 0) {          /* Note: if <startBit> and <endBit> are in */
        count += table[value];     /* same byte, this loop gets skipped. */
        index++;
        value = buffer[index];
        numBits -= 8;
    }

    if (numBits < 0) {             /* mask-out any bits following <endBit> */
        bits   = 8 - (endBit & 7);
        mask   = 0xff << bits;
        value &= mask;
    }

    count += table[value];

    *pTotal = count;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Function header updated.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood the code but still I think the code can be made more concise. I suspect that you misunderstood the question. It is not 'consecutive' set bits. But just set bits in a 'contiguous' memory.

Comment: @Bhaskar: The function header description was wrong.  Thanks for catching that. :)  The idea of the code is to use a lookup table to count the bits set in the range.  Special care must be taken at the start and end as these are not likely to be full bytes.  Bits that precede the starting bit and bits that follow the ending bit are masked out before looking the value up in the table.  This algorithm also covers the case where the start and end bits are in the same byte.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the industry you applied in, look-up tables might not be an acceptable means of optimization while platform / compiler specific optimizations are. Knowing that most compilers and CPU instruction sets have a pop count instruction, I'd go for this. It's a simplicity vs. performance trade-off though because right now I'm still iterating over a list of chars.

Also note that contrary to most answers I assume start and end are byte-offsets because it's not specified in the question that they're not and it's the default in most cases.

```
int countSetBits(void *ptr, int start, int end )
{
    assert(start < end);

    unsigned char *s = ((unsigned char*)ptr + start);
    unsigned char *e = ((unsigned char*)ptr + end);

    int r = 0;

    while(s != e)
    {
        // __builtin_clz is not defined for 0 input.
        if(*s) r += 32 - __builtin_clz(*s);
        s++;
    }

    return r;
}
```